# Collapse-o-matic plugin and Wordpress Comments how to loop?

Tags: wordpress, loops, plugins

I am trying to get this plugin "Collapse-O-Matic" to work with the comments area of a wordpress site. This plugin can basically collapse a section and expand it, but what I specifically need for it to do is to collapse and expand individual comments rather than the whole comment section.

I found out where to do it, and I was able to add it, but it is only adding the collapse to the first comment "comment_text()" and not to the rest of the comments, which I would assume means that I need to add some kind of loop, and this is where I am stuck.

Here is the code:

```
     <span class="collapseomatic" id="comments<?php the_ID(); ?>">Expand</span>
    <span id="swap-comments<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="collapseomatic" style="display: none;">Collapse</span>
    <div id="target-comments<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="collapseomatic_content">

    <?php comment_text() ?>

    <div class="reply">
    <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('add_below' => $add_below, 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (1): // 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a real-time commenting plugin like Livefyre or Disqus, the following code should do the trick:

```
 <?php do_shortcode('[expand title="read more" swaptitle="read less"]'.comments_template().'[/expand]'); ?>
```

Livefyre resists my best efforts to collapse it, and it's very frustrating.